# ¿Cómo hacer encabezado en Excel con Python?

Tags: python, excel

Soy nuevo y apenas me estoy adentrando a lo que es hacer código.
Quiero hacer un encabezado donde sea de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa hace la conversión del puerto serial por RS2323 a txt, después lo convierte a csv y lo ultimo lo convierte a excel pero sin formato, desde la primera columna y renglón empieza a guardar los datos. Hay alguna manera de poder hacer en código; un formato así o parecido para que lo guarde de esa forma.
El código es este:

```
import pandas as pd 
import xlwt as xl 
import serial, csv ,time, os 

# De archivo txt a csv
def to_csv():
    dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('Docs\comas.txt')
    dataframe1.to_csv('Docs\csvarch.csv',index=None)

    print ('txt a csv listo')

 # De archivo csv a excel 
def to_database():
    time1=time.localtime(time.time())
    wb=xl.Workbook()
    sh=wb.add_sheet('OCLUSSION')
    with open('Docs\csvarch.csv','r') as r:
         reader=csv.reader(r)
         sh.write('\n')
         for t, row in enumerate(reader):
             for c, val in enumerate(row):
                 sh.write(t,c,val)
                 wb.save('Docs\Database_{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}. 
                         {4}.xls'.format(time1[0],time1[1],time1[2],time1[3],time1[5]))
                 print('Base de datos subida')

            

if __name__ =='__main__':

#Se asigna el puerto de entra y la velocidad de los bits 
   ser = serial.Serial('COM6','9600')
   time.sleep(2)
   if ser.isOpen():
      print('PUERTO SERIE CONECTADO')
      print('Estado del puerto serie: ',ser.isOpen())
      print('Nombre del dispositivo conectado: ',ser.name)
      print('\n################################################################\n')

   else:
      print('Puerto serie fallo')
    
   try:
      num=0
      while True:
          f=open('Docs\comas.txt','a')
          getBytes=b''
          csvarch=0
          xlsarch=0
          count=ser.inWaiting()
          if count>0:
             data=ser.read(count)
             if data!=getBytes:
                print (data)
                print (num)
                f.write(data.decode('utf-8'))
                f.write('\n')
                num+=1
                getBytes=data
                if num==10:
                    f.close()
                    print('Datos subidos')
                    ser.flushInput()
                    csvarch=1
                    if csvarch==1:
                        to_csv()
                        xlsarch=1
                        if xlsarch==1:
                            to_database()
                            num+=1
                            if num==11:
                                os.remove('Docs/comas.txt')
                                os.remove('Docs/csvarch.csv')
                                num=0

   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       print('Puerto serie cerrado')
    
       if ser!=None:
          ser.close()
```

He intentado con la librería xlwt pero no me tienen mucha información para el manejo de los formatos, nomas de leer y escribir, me ayudaría cualquier tipo de referencia para dejar de estar estancado en donde ando ahorita. Gracias por su tiempo